# Can't get the localStorage to save my edit of an object (Js, CSS, HTML 5)

Tags: javascript, node.js, html, local-storage, yeoman

I started learning Webapps with Node, yeoman, bower, bootstrap, handlebars from a video tutorial. I'm not getting any errors but my data fixture is not storing into localStorage after an item is edited.

Here the Js, the editEntry Function is the point at which I'm not getting the changes saved inside localStorage. If I call saveEntry instead, it'll add the edited item to the localStorage array at the last index. But if I call editEntry i get to the alert() which means the item just needs to replace it's old self with the edited version. Unfortunately it doesn't. Afterwards localStorage has the same strings as before. I'm stuck.

But here is the Kicker, you may not need to bother reading the code. I'm running this in a folder called "your-code". Mean while, in another folder called "chapter 7" that came with the video tutorial, lies the exact same code (I tested it) and it works perfectly.

Quick recap: the exact same code is able to 'save the edit to localStorage' as intended in the teacher's folder but not in my folder! So if the code is not the problem, what is it? All I want to do is edit the data that's in localStorage from within the WebApp while it's running.

```
//functions
var hideShowFunction = function (evt) {
    var eventTarget = $(evt.target);
    var data = eventTarget.data();
    $('.view').removeClass('active');
    $(data.target).addClass('active');

    renderTemplate(data.target, data.item);
}

var renderTemplate = function(target, itemId) {
    var targetTemplate = target + '-template';
    var source = $(targetTemplate).html();
    var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
    //var data = {beers: beers};
    //var data = {title: "This is the title", body: "This is the body!"};
    // actual data!
    var data;
    if (itemId) { 
        var arr = $.grep( beers, function(beer, i){
            return beer.id == itemId;
        });

        data = arr[0];
    }
    else {
        data = { beers: beers };
    }
    var html = template(data);
    $(target).html(html);
}

$.fn.serializeObject = function()
{
    var o = {};
    var a = this.serializeArray();
    $.each(a, function() {
        if (o[this.name] !== undefined) {
            if (!o[this.name].push) {
                o[this.name] = [o[this.name]];
            }
            o[this.name].push(this.value || '');
        } else {
            o[this.name] = this.value || '';
        }
    });
    return o;
};

var saveEntry = function(result) {      //finds the highest id
  var highestId = Math.max.apply(Math, beers.map(function(o){return o.id;}));
  result.id = highestId > 0 ? highestId + 1 : 1;
  beers.push(result);
  localStorage.beers = JSON.stringify(beers);
}

var editEntry = function(result) {
  var resultInt = parseInt(result.id);      //converts string to int
  result.id = resultInt;
  for (i in beers) {
    if (beers[i].id === resultInt ) {      //find loc to overwrite
      alert('id match');
      beers[i] = result;
      localStorage.beers = JSON.stringify(beers);
      break;
    }
  }
}

//listeners
$('body').on('click', '.view-switcher', function(evt){
    hideShowFunction(evt);
}); // eslint-disable-line no-console

$('body').on('submit','#add-form', function(evt){
  var result = $(this).serializeObject();
  saveEntry(result);
  renderTemplate('#full-list');
  return false;
});

$('body').on('submit','#edit-form', function(evt){
  var result = $(this).serializeObject();
  editEntry(result);
  renderTemplate('#full-list');
  return false;
});

//storage
var beers;
if (Modernizr.localstorage) {
    if (localStorage.beers) {
        beers = JSON.parse(localStorage.beers);}
    else {
        beers = [];}
}
else {
    console.log('does not work');
}


//init
renderTemplate('#full-list');
```

Here's the scripts

```
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Beerlist</title>
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/apple-touch-icon.png">
  <!-- Place favicon.ico and apple-touch-icon.png in the root directory -->

  <!-- build:css(.) styles/vendor.css -->
  <!-- bower:css -->
  <!-- endbower -->
  <!-- endbuild -->
  <!-- build:css(.tmp) styles/main.css -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.css">
  <!-- endbuild -->
  <!-- build:js scripts/vendor/modernizr.js -->
  <script src="/bower_components/modernizr/modernizr.js"></script>
  <!-- endbuild -->

</head>
<body>
    <!--[if lt IE 10]>
      <p class="browsehappy">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">upgrade your browser</a> to improve your experience.</p>
      <![endif]-->


      <div class="container">
        <div class="header clearfix">
          <div class="clearfix">
            <h3 class="text-muted pull-left">Beerlist</h3>
            <span class="label label-success pull-right" id="network-status">Online</span>
          </div>
          <a data-target="#add-item" href="#" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary view-switcher pull-right">Add</a>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-12 view active" id="full-list">
            <!-- renders here -->
          </div><!--end full-list -->
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-12 view" id="add-item">
          <!-- renders here -->
        </div><!-- end add-item -->

        <div class="col-lg-12 view" id="edit-item">
          <!-- renders here -->
        </div><!-- end edit-item -->

        <div class="col-lg-12 view" id="item-detail">
          <!-- renders here -->
        </div><!-- end item-detail -->

      </div>

    <script id="full-list-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
            <div class="list-group">
              {{#if beers}}
              {{#each beers}}
              <a data-item={{id}} data-target="#item-detail" href="#" class="list-group-item view-switcher">{{title}}
              </a>
              {{/each}}
              {{else}}
              <h3>Click 'Add' Item</h3>
              {{/if}}
            </div>
          </script>

          <script id="add-item-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
              <h3>Add Item</h3>
              <form role="form" id="add-form">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="title">Title</label>
                  <input class="form-control" id="title" name="title" type="text">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="title">Description</label>
                  <textarea class="form-control" id="description" name="description" type="text"></textarea>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group clearfix">
                  <button id="transcribe" class="btn btn-lg btn-info pull-right">Transcribe</button>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group clearfix">
                  <button id="upload-photo" class="btn btn-lg btn-success pull-right">Upload a Photo</button>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <p><strong>Current Location: Lat 37, Long 122</strong></p>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                  <button data-target="#full-list" id="cancel-add-item" class="btn btn-lg btn-default pull-left view-switcher">Cancel</button>
                  <button data-target="#full-list" id="submit-item" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary pull-right view-switcher">Submit</button>
                </div>
              </form>
          </script>

          <script id="edit-item-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
          <h3>Edit Item</h3>
              <form role="form" id="edit-form">
              <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{id}}">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="title">Title</label>
                  <input class="form-control item-data" id="title" name="title" type="text" value="{{title}}">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="title">Description</label>
                  <textarea class="form-control item-data" id="description" name="description">{{description}}</textarea>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group clearfix">
                  <button id="transcribe" class="btn btn-lg btn-info pull-right">Transcribe</button>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group clearfix">
                  <button id="upload-photo" class="btn btn-lg btn-success pull-right">Upload a Photo</button>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <p><strong>Current Location: Lat 37, Long 122</strong></p>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                  <button data-target="#full-list" id="cancel-edit-item" class="btn btn-lg btn-default pull-left view-switcher">Cancel</button>
                  <button data-target="#full-list" id="#edit-item" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary pull-right view-switcher">Submit</button>
                </div>
              </form>
          </script>

          <script id="item-detail-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
            <h3>Item Detail</h3>
            <div class="list-group">
              <p id="show-title" class="list-group-item">{{title}}</p>
              <p id="show-description" class="list-group-item">{{description}}</p>
              <p id="show-image" class="list-group-item">
                <span class="label">Image:</span>
                <img src="">
              </p>
              <p>Current Location: Lat {{location.latitude}}, Long {{location.longitude}}</p>
            </div>
            <p>
              <button data-target="#full-list" id="back-to-list" class="btn btn-lg btn-default view-switcher">Back to List</button>
              <button data-item={{id}} data-target="#edit-item" id="edit-item" class="view-switcher btn btn-lg btn-default pull-right">Edit</button>
            </p>
          </script>

      <!-- build:js(.) scripts/vendor.js -->
      <!-- bower:js -->
      <script src="/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
      <!-- endbower -->
      <!-- endbuild -->


      <!-- build:js(.) scripts/plugins.js -->
      <script src="/bower_components/bootstrap-sass/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/affix.js"></script>
      <script src="/bower_components/bootstrap-sass/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/alert.js"></script>
      <script src="/bower_components/bootstrap-sass/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/dropdown.js"></script>
      <script src="/bower_components/bootstrap-sass/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/tooltip.js"></script>
      <script src="/bower_components/bootstrap-sass/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/modal.js"></script>
      <script src="/bower_components/bootstrap-sass/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/transition.js"></script>
      <script src="/bower_components/bootstrap-sass/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/button.js"></script>
      <script src="/bower_components/bootstrap-sass/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/popover.js"></script>
      <script src="/bower_components/bootstrap-sass/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/carousel.js"></script>
      <script src="/bower_components/bootstrap-sass/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/scrollspy.js"></script>
      <script src="/bower_components/bootstrap-sass/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/collapse.js"></script>
      <script src="/bower_components/bootstrap-sass/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/tab.js"></script>
      <script src="/bower_components/handlebars/handlebars.js"></script>
      <!-- endbuild -->


      <!-- build:js(.tmp) scripts/main.js -->
      <script src="scripts/main.js"></script>
      <!-- endbuild -->

      <!-- Google Analytics: change UA-XXXXX-X to be your site's ID. -->
      <script>
      (function(b,o,i,l,e,r){b.GoogleAnalyticsObject=l;b[l]||(b[l]=
        function(){(b[l].q=b[l].q||[]).push(arguments)});b[l].l=+new Date;
      e=o.createElement(i);r=o.getElementsByTagName(i)[0];
      e.src='https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js';
      r.parentNode.insertBefore(e,r)}(window,document,'script','ga'));
      ga('create','UA-XXXXX-X');ga('send','pageview');
      </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

and the CSS

```
$icon-font-path: "../bower_components/bootstrap-sass/assets/fonts/bootstrap/";

// bower:scss
@import "bower_components/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/_bootstrap.scss";
// endbower

    .browsehappy {
        margin: 0.2em 0;
        background: #ccc;
        color: #000;
        padding: 0.2em 0;
    }

    /* Space out content a bit */
    body {
        padding-top: 20px;
        padding-bottom: 20px;
    }

    /* Everything but the jumbotron gets side spacing for mobile first views */
    .header,
    .marketing,
    .footer {
        padding-left: 15px;
        padding-right: 15px;
    }

    /* Custom page header */
    .header {
        border-bottom: 1px solid #e5e5e5;

        /* Make the masthead heading the same height as the navigation */
        h3 {
            margin-top: 0;
            margin-bottom: 0;
            line-height: 40px;
            padding-bottom: 19px;
        }
    }

    /* Custom page footer */
    .footer {
        padding-top: 19px;
        color: #777;
        border-top: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
    }

    .container-narrow > hr {
        margin: 30px 0;
    }

    /* Main marketing message and sign up button */
    .jumbotron {
        text-align: center;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
        .btn {
            font-size: 21px;
            padding: 14px 24px;
        }
    }

    /* Supporting marketing content */
    .marketing {
        margin: 40px 0;
        p + h4 {
            margin-top: 28px;
        }
    }

    /* Responsive: Portrait tablets and up */
    @media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
        .container {
            max-width: 730px;
        }

        /* Remove the padding we set earlier */
        .header,
        .marketing,
        .footer {
            padding-left: 0;
            padding-right: 0;
        }

        /* Space out the masthead */
        .header {
            margin-bottom: 30px;
        }

        /* Remove the bottom border on the jumbotron for visual effect */
        .jumbotron {
            border-bottom: 0;
        }
    }

    /* styles for beerlist/birdwatching app */
    .view {
      display: none;
    }

    .view.active {
      display: block;
    }

    .header {
        padding-bottom: 20px;
    }
```

Comment: is your page on http?

Comment: It's on localhost so I think that means it is using the http protocol. Here is what it looks like:

first I click edit
http://i524.photobucket.com/albums/cc325/rhsnipes/edit%20item%201st%20cap.jpeg

after editing I click submit
http://i524.photobucket.com/albums/cc325/rhsnipes/edit%20item%202nd%20cap.jpeg

then I see the item has not been changed
http://i524.photobucket.com/albums/cc325/rhsnipes/edit%20item%203rd%20cap.jpeg